# NDSolve: Solve PDE with constraints in a subregion

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I want to extend a PDE-FEM problem(heat equation, boundary temperature given), which works as expected:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
region = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1, {x, y}];

netz = ToElementMesh[region(*,"MeshElementType"\[Rule]TriangleElement*)];
U = NDSolveValue[{
D[u[t, x, y], t] - Laplacian[u[t, x, y], {x, y}] == 0,
u[0, x, y] == If[0 < x < 1 && 0 < y < 1, 0, 1] ,

DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 1, x == 0 || x == 1 || y == 0 || y == 1]  
}, u, Element[{x, y}, netz], {t, 0, 1}]
```

Now I want to give an additional consistent constraint  u[t,x,y]==1 in a subregion (x - 0.5)^2 + (y - .5)^2 <= 0.2^2.

Is this possible with the actual Solvers? I tried several variants like

```
subregion = 
ImplicitRegion[(x - 0.5)^2 + (y - .5)^2 <= 0.2^2 && t >= 0 , {t, x, 
y}];   

U = NDSolveValue[{
D[u[t, x, y], t] - Laplacian[u[t, x, y], {x, y}] == 0,
u[0, x, y] == If[0 < x < 1 && 0 < y < 1, 0, 1] ,
u[Element[{t,x,y},subregion]]==1,
DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 1, x == 0 || x == 1 || y == 0 || y == 1]  
}, u, Element[{x, y}, netz], {t, 0, 1}]
```

but didn't succeed.

Any idea how to handle this boundary problem?
Thank you!

I tried to keep the example as simple as possible. Clearly the temperature constraints in the subdomains could be different, not necessary constant, but also time dependent. The underlying problem would be "heating of a plate" -process.

Comment: Please elaborate on "didn't succeed".  What happened when you ran this code and variants?

Comment: Thank you for your hint. Mathematica give's the error NDSolveValue::dvlen: The function u[{t,x,y}\ [Element]ImplicitRegion[Plus[<<2>>]^2+Plus[<<2>>]^2<=0.04&&t>=0,{t,x,y}]] does not have the same number of arguments as independent variables (3). which exceeds my Mathematica experience!

Comment: Are the two regions made oft two different materials?

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
region = ImplicitRegion[(x - 0.5)^2 + (y - .5)^2 > 
    0.2^2, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}}];
netz = ToElementMesh[region];
U = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x, y], t] - Laplacian[u[t, x, y], {x, y}] == 
     0, u[0, x, y] == If[0 < x < 1 && 0 < y < 1, 0, 1], 
    DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 1, 
     x == 0 || x == 1 || y == 0 || y == 1]}, u, 
   Element[{x, y}, netz], {t, 0, 1}];
ContourPlot[U[1, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] netz]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to keep the example as simple as possible. Clearly the temperature constraints in the subdomains could be different, not necessary constant, but also time dependent. The underlying problem would be "heating of a plate" -process.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann please do not use answers to post updates to the question or comments for answers. Edit the question or post a comment instead. You can do that for own posts despite low rep. If you have a problem with two accounts please see: [/help/merging-accounts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)